# Bypass onBootstrap() Function

Tags: php, zend-framework, laminas

I have the following problem. Currently I work on a project where I should develop a new module. The problem is, that the main module just uses the onBootstrap function to validate the request (every) and if it not on the route of the main module, it returns a notfound 404 error page.

Now all my new routes on my new module just dont work cause onBootstrap() just kicks in before. Is there a way to check in the main module if the route just hit and if every module dont find routes to get the 404 error page?

Im pretty new to this framework D=.

example:

MainModule.php

```
class Module
{

...

onBootstrap() 
{
$request = ...->getRequest();
if($request->isNotValid()) {
return new 404Response();
}
}

...

}
```

```
class SideModule
{

...

// Never triggered
public function indexAction() 
{
print("Hello World");
}

...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should depend on a 404 resolver later in the code, not during bootstrap of your first module. I'd suggest getting rid of the code that returns the 404 response in MainModule `onBootstrap()` method and instead depend on `Laminas\Mvc\View\Http\RouteNotFoundStrategy` that's automatically injected during Application bootstrap (see `Laminas\Mvc\Application::bootstrap()`, the part where defaultListeners are attached. ViewManager is one of the defaultListeners, and ViewManager on its behalf attaches `HttpRouteNotFoundStrategy` in the `Laminas\Mvc\View\Http\ViewManager::bootstrap()` method).

RouteNotFoundStrategy not only will set a 404 status code to your `MvcEvent->getResponse()` object, but will also render a not-found page which you can
customize any way you like. See https://docs.laminas.dev/laminas-mvc/services/ for more information.